# Ability to Associate Newly Created Leads with an Existing Campaign

Tags: apex, trigger, leads, campaign

I am trying to figure out a way to associate a lead, upon creation, with an existing campaign.

I know this would involve an apex trigger/class, but I'm not sure of how to do it.

The way I want it to behave is for the trigger to "look" to a text field that will contain the Salesforce campaign name or campaign ID (whichever is easiest) and then add the lead to that campaign upon saving.

Comment: Did my answer help you or at least point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a `after insert` trigger on `Lead` that creates a `CampaignMember` object(s) and inserts it.

The `CampaignMember` object requires the ID of the Campaign (`CampaignID` field) and the ID of the Lead (`LeadID` field) to create it (you can also use Contacts with the `ContactID` field), you can also set the `Status` of your `CampaignMember`.

Once the `CampaignMember` object has been created your Leads should show up in the Campaign Members related list of the relavent Campaign.

Comment: I think you mean: `after insert` trigger - before insert won't have access to the lead.id

Comment: @crop1645 Good catch, this is what happens when I answer things late at night on my phone.